# Is there a way to tell the scala compiler to generate private methods when compiling anonymous scala functions?

Tags: scala, jakarta-ee

I have this code in `Foo.scala`

```
object Foo extends App
{
    def bar() = () => println("hello")
    bar()()
}
```

If I run

```
scalac Foo.scala
```

I obtain three `.class` files:

- Foo$.class
- Foo$delayedInit$body.class
- Foo.class

If then I run

`javap 'Foo$.class'`

I get on stdout

```
Compiled from "Foo.scala"
public final class Foo$ implements scala.App {
  public static Foo$ MODULE$;
  public static {};
  public java.lang.String[] args();
  public void delayedInit(scala.Function0<scala.runtime.BoxedUnit>);
  public void main(java.lang.String[]);
  public long executionStart();
  public java.lang.String[] scala$App$$_args();
  public void scala$App$$_args_$eq(java.lang.String[]);
  public scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer<scala.Function0<scala.runtime.BoxedUnit>> scala$App$$initCode();
  public void scala$App$_setter_$executionStart_$eq(long);
  public final void scala$App$_setter_$scala$App$$initCode_$eq(scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer<scala.Function0<scala.runtime.BoxedUnit>>);
  public scala.Function0<scala.runtime.BoxedUnit> bar();
  public static final void $anonfun$bar$1();
  public final void delayedEndpoint$Foo$1();
}
```

As you can see the lambda that is returned from the `bar` method is
compiled into `public static final void $anonfun$bar$1();`
I would like to be able to have all the lambda used in my scala code compiled as private method instead of public ones (it shouldn't be a problem when those functions are just local method variables, since they can only be accessed from within the method in which they are declared). Is there a way to achieve that?

P.S.
I'm asking because I'm using Scala to create Java EE's EJB classes and EJB classes used with no-interface view cannot have methods that are both public and final (it must be possible to instantiate a subclass that overrides all the public methods to create a proxy)

Comment: Lambda is a "value" in Scala, so it can be passed outside of `Foo`. How can you do it if you declare it private?

Comment: You mean that when the lambda returned by `bar()` is called from another class, under the hood it is simply calling `$anonfun$bar$1()` on an instance of `Foo$`?

Comment: The method in question is static, and static methods can't be overridden, so I'm not understanding how this would create a conflict with EJB proxying.

Comment: @SethTisue the erorr message I get from the application server is `Business view method $anonfun$methodName$1 declared final in full.class.Name`